# How can I write a test for $cookieStore like this?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I have 2 roles: one is admin, this another is normal user. Admin can navigate to item-detail page, and normal user can not. Hence, I store user's role in "globals" cookies when they are login. I get their role from cookieStore to check which one can navigate to item-detail page. This function works well. However, I have no idea how to write a test for $cookieStore in checkUserRole function:

```
angular.module('config', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) 
{
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', 
    {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login-page.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .state('index',
    {
        url: '/index',
        templateUrl: 'bridge.html'
    })
    .state('item-detail',
    {
        url: '/index/item-detail/:Name',
        templateUrl: 'item-detail.html',
        controller: 'myCtrl',
        resolve:
        {
            checkUserRole: function($cookieStore)
            {
                if($cookieStore.get('globals').currentUser.userRole === 'user')
                {
                    return state.go('index');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And, here is my test case:

```
describe('config', function()
{
    var $scope, $state, $cookieStore, userRole;
    beforeEach(function()
    {
        module('config', function($provide)
        {
            $provide.value('$cookieStore', { get: 'globals' });
        });
        inject(function($injector, $templateCache)
        {
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $cookieStore = $injector.get('$cookieStore');
            $templateCache.put('login-page.html', '');
            $templateCache.put('bridge.html', '');
            $templateCache.put('item-detail.html', '');
        });
    });
    it('home page', function()
    {
        $scope.$apply();
        expect($state.current.name).toBe('login');
        expect($state.current.templateUrl).toBe('login-page.html');
        expect($state.current.controller).toBe('LoginController');
    });
    it('login page', function()
    {
        $scope.$apply(function()
        {
            $state.go('login');         
        });
        expect($state.current.name).toBe('login');
        expect($state.current.templateUrl).toBe('login-page.html');
        expect($state.current.controller).toBe('LoginController');
    });
    it('items page', function()
    {
        $scope.$apply(function()
        {
            $state.go('index');         
        });
        expect($state.current.name).toBe('index');
        expect($state.current.templateUrl).toBe('bridge.html');
    });
    it('item-detail page', function()
    {
        spyOn($cookieStore, 'get').and.callFake(function()
        {
            return 'user';
        });
        expect($cookieStore.get('globals')).toBe('user');
        $scope.$apply(function()
        {
            $state.go('item-detail');
        });
        expect($state.current.name).toBe('item-detail');
        expect($state.current.templateUrl).toBe('item-detail.html');
        expect($state.current.controller).toBe('myCtrl');
        expect($state.href('item-detail', { Name: 'lumia-950'})).toEqual('#/index/item-detail/lumia-950');
    });
});
```

My question is: How can I write a test for `$cookieStore.get('globals').currentUser.userRole`? or how can I mock it to test what if user's role is user?.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of angular you're using but `$cookieStore` is now deprecated, prefer using `$cookies` instead ([see doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)).

There are at least 3 ways to proceed :

Using **Jasmine with Angular** `$cookie` (from v1.4.x) :

```
describe('config module', function(){
    var $cookies;

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module('config');
        angular.mock.inject(function(_$cookies_){
            $cookies  = _$cookies_;
        });
    });

    it('should have a "globals" cookie with "user" value', function(){
        var globals = $cookies.getObject('globals');

        expect(globals.currentUser.userRole).toBe('user');
    });
});
```

Using **Jasmine with pure JavaScript** :

```
describe('config module', function(){
    it('should have a "globals" cookie with "user" value', function(){
        var globals = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)globals\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
        globals = JSON.parse(globals);

        expect(globals.currentUser.userRole).toBe('user');
    });
});
```

Using **Jasmine with Protractor** (e2e test) :

```
describe('config module', function(){
    it('should have a "globals" cookie with "user" value', function(){
        var globals = JSON.parse(browser.manage().getCookie('globals'));
        expect(globals.currentUser.userRole).toBe('user');
    });
});
```

Here Protractor gives us `browser` global variable to handle browser related behavior.

Note that `JSON.parse()` is used to unserialized the cookie string value and parse it to an usable JavaScript object.

example :

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "foo" : "bar" }');
console.log(obj.foo);    //print 'bar' in the console
```

**IMPORTANT:**

> In your application, use only 1.4.7 version of Angular libraries with the Angular 1.4.7 Core.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I really appropriate your help. Can you explain more about  `JSON.parse(browser.manage(). )` for me? Because Jasmine warning "browser is not defined in file". I use version 1.4.7 for angularJS and 1.5.0-beta.1 for angularJS cookies

Comment: I have updated the post to give you more details. Please give it a look and tell me if you need more information

Comment: Sorry, but it still not works. Do I need add something more? Because Jasmine warning that "unpr?p0=%24cookiesProvider%20%3C-%20%24cookies"

Comment: You have to load angular, angular-cookies and angular-mocks libraries for your tests to work properly. Please check that they are correctly loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got your idea.

Comment: Not yet. I will continue later because I have another work to do first. Thank for your help. :)